# Is there a way to call join on multiple thread simultaneously in C++？

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

The well known [`select()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) enable program the block on multiple sockets until one of them become available and need to be handled. Suppose I have multiple threads, each doing its own task, I don't call join and block only on the first thread. Is there a way to handle it in c++?

Also, is there a non-blocking version of join, so `thread_select` can be implemented?

Comment: As alternative, [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) has [`wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for).

Comment: On Windows, use WaitForMultipleObjects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects

Comment: Rather than wait on multiple threads, have the threads place their results on a (thread-safe) fifo/queue.  Then your main thread just has to block waiting for the first result to be pushed onto the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to do for threads what `select` does for descriptors. So, if `select` waits until *any one* member of some set of descriptors has data to be read, does that mean you want a way to wait until any one member of some set of threads has terminated?

If so, then "yes," there's a way, but "no," there isn't any standard library method that you can call. You'll have to write the code yourself.

One way, would be to use a [`std::counting_semaphore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore).

- Construct the semaphore with its internal permit counter initialized to zero,
- Have each of the awaited threads `release` a permit to the semaphore just before the thread dies, and
- Have the waiting thread call `sem.acquire()`.

The `acquire` function will return as soon as any one of the awaited threads has released a permit (i.e., as soon as any one of the awaited threads has finished doing whatever it was supposed to do.)

---

Another way would be to use a boolean flag and a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). The flag would be initialized to `false`, and the awaited threads would set it true and `notify` the condition variable before ending. The awaiting thread would loop, calling `cv.wait()` until the flag became true.